# Run script for each image in the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a function which automatically adds a link back to an image posted to my blog from Flickr and it works well when there's only one image. As soon as more images are added to the post, my function is adding the title for every picture in the post to the caption and I can't seem to figure out why that's happening.

**jQuery**

```
$(".needs-credit").each(function() {
          // Grab the image URL to put through the API call
          var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');

          // If "flickr.com" is in the URL, run the function
          if (!/flickr\.com$/i.test(imgSrc)) {

            // Get the photo ID from the src
            photoId = imgSrc.replace(/(.+\.[a-z]{2,4})\/(\d{3,5})\/(\d{7,15})(?:(?!ab).)*/ig, '$3');

            //Call the Flicmr API to get the photo info as JSON
            var apiUrl = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getInfo&api_key=c8c95356e465b8d7398ff2847152740e&photo_id=" + photoId + "&format=json&jsoncallback=?";

            // Put a credit after the image using the JSON data
            // NOTE that changing $('img') to $(this) breaks the script, I think because it's nested.
            $.getJSON(apiUrl, function(data){
                  $('img').after('<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/'+data.photo.owner.nsid+'/'+data.photo.id+'/">'+data.photo.title._content+ ' by ' +data.photo.owner.username+'</a>');
            })
          }
        })
```

I've got an ugly **[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/eBwpK)** showing the problem. The only thing I can guess is that I'm specifying the class somewhere twice, but I can't seem to figure out where.

Comment: $('img').after() hits all images, $('img', this).after() would hit just ones under the calling container...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which image you're uploading the caption for. As @dandavis said, `$("img")` will get *ALL* the images, which is why every picture is getting the caption.

Inside the `.each` function, `this` refers to the current element. However, since you're inside the callback function of `.getJson`, you need to pass it in some way:

```
//Option 1 - Using Closure
var $this = $(this);

$.getJSON(apiUrl, function(data){
    $this.after('<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/'+data.photo.owner.nsid+'/'+data.photo.id+'/">'+data.photo.title._content+ ' by ' +data.photo.owner.username+'</a>');
})

//Option 2 - Explicitly binding this
$.getJSON(apiUrl, function(data){
    $(this).after('<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/'+data.photo.owner.nsid+'/'+data.photo.id+'/">'+data.photo.title._content+ ' by ' +data.photo.owner.username+'</a>');
}.bind(this))
```

Comment: Ahhh...gotcha. Closure worked perfectly. Thanks for breaking it down for me!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(this).after('<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/'+data.photo.owner.nsid+'/'+data.photo.id+'/">'+data.photo.title._content+ ' by ' +data.photo.owner.username+'</a>');
```

instead of

```
$('img').after('<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/'+data.photo.owner.nsid+'/'+data.photo.id+'/">'+data.photo.title._content+ ' by ' +data.photo.owner.username+'</a>');
```